# ZF2 mime type problems

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework2, vagrant, mime

And happy 2016 ;-)

I'm actually trying to learn ZF2, and I have some problems that I dont' know how to resolve.

First, you have to know that the project is running under vagrant.
I have 2 modules:

- Admin
- Application

I have a layout for each module.

In the admin layout module, I have some style and JS file:
All this JS and CSS files are in the public folder.

```
<?= $this
        ->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'))
        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'))
        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'))
        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css'))
        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/AdminLTE.min.css'))
        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/skins/skin-blue.min.css'))
; ?>

<?=
    $this->inlineScript()
        ->prependFile($this->basePath('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'))
        ->prependFile($this->basePath('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'))
        ->prependFile($this->basePath('js/app.min.js'))
;?>
```

For some CSS file, I have errors in the browser:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

And for JS, I have problems too:

> Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

I know this JS error, it append when you load boostrap.js before jquery.js.
But here, it's not the case!

I don't know if the problem comes from my layout integration of CSS and JS files, or if I forgot something in the controller, or in the configuration.
May be it's a problem with vagrant too?

I also have a htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Please, I need some help because i'm lost ;-)

Thanks for any advice/documentation or else.

Comment: Regarding the Js problem, `$this->prependFile` add the requested fiel BEFORE the others you alredy have. To mantain the order you should use `$this->appendFile()`

Comment: Thanks for help, but I always have the same error message

Comment: You should update your code from prependFile to appendFile then, as the latter would be expected in your case, and certainly would seem to be giving you the wrong loading order. Did you already look at the output page source?

Comment: What is the generated HTML ? What do you get if your try to access you jquery.min.js file directly ?